# Recursive method in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm creating a recursive method in Nuxt, can I do it?

Here is my component:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      auxitems: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    orderRecursive(items, auxitems) {
      items.data.forEach((element) => {
        auxitems.push(element)
      })
      if (items.child.length > 0) {
        this.orderRecursive(items.child, auxitems)
      } else {
        //
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The struct items is like:

```
items= [
  data: [{array}],
  child: [{data, child}]
]
```

My intention is order all data in one array, then, I can show in view.
My method `orderRecursive()` is not working, can you tell me why?

Comment: You've spelled the word `element` wrong in your `push` statement

Comment: I've edited your question and fixed some code errors. Please double-check if it's anyhow better now.

Comment: Hi, any news on this one?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: @CesarBhering can't really help with just that.